# Find substring matches within a string[] using a variable

Tags: c#, arrays, regex, string, for-loop

I am trying to use  a for-loop to go through a pdf excel file and find all of the lines that contain the employee ID, and add the full line of the matches to a  list contained inside a function.
How do I iterate through the string[] and find where all of  the first 8 characters match?

Example of employee info

```
98113457 Abaile, Volker DB Vacation Available Days
48976143 Asif,  Gamal  DB Vacation Available
65282785 Affe, Sandra DB Vacation Available Days
98113457 Abaile, Volker DB Time Account Hours
65282785 Affe, Sandra DB Vacation Carryover Days
48976143 Asif, Gamal  DB Time Account Hours
```

Code:

```
string[] words3 = words2.ToArray();  

for (int j = 7;  j < words2.Count(); j++)
{ 
    string  results  = null;
    //"results" is the current employee information line  
    results = @"words3[j]";

    //The ID number of that employee 
    string firstResults = results.Substring(0, 8);

    //Find and get all of the lines that start with employee ID from string[] words3
    if (firstResults.IndexOf(words3) != -1)
    { 
        //pass the full lines with all of the employee's information to a function
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `results = word3[j];`?

Comment: This code and your description don't seem to match and it is unclear what _exactly_ you want this code to do. What is `results = @"words3[j]";` supposed to do anyway?

Comment: if you are reading from excel, why not create an Employee class and instantiate it with the information in the excel. It would then provide more options for how you want to use the list.

Comment: @user1666620 I am reading form a PDF file with an excel like format

Comment: @CodeCaster I am trying to find all of the matches for each employee... For Example: find all of the lines containing  info belonging to  Sandra add them to a list so i can create a new file

Comment: @Cscience18: What variable contains the employeeID you are searching for?

Comment: @mellamokb firstResults contains the employee ID ... I have changed the code to     if ( words3.Contains(firstResults))
                     { 
                         //pass the full lines with all of the employee's information to a function
                        Console.Out.WriteLine(" These are matches" + words3);
                     }
                } but the if statement did not work

Comment: @Cscience18: That's the variable that contains the employee ID from the *current row*.  When you say find where all of the "first 8 characters match", *match what*?  Match a specific id like `98113457`?  Or any of a list?  Or anything that looks like 8 digits is valid?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to parse above lines and you have same type of lines then try it

```
var words = new List<string>
{
     "98113457 Abaile, Volker DB Vacation Available Days",
     "48976143 Asif,  Gamal  DB Vacation Available",
     "65282785 Affe, Sandra DB Vacation Available Days",
     "98113457 Abaile, Volker DB Time Account Hours",
     "65282785 Affe, Sandra DB Vacation Carryover Days",
     "48976143 Asif, Gamal  DB Time Account Hours"
};
foreach (var word in words)
{
     var id = word.Substring(0, 8);
     var name = word.Split(',')[0].Split(' ')[1];
     var type = word.Split(',')[1].Trim().Split(' ')[0];
     var db = word.Split(',')[1].Trim().Split(' ')[1];
     var index = word.IndexOf(db) + 2;
     var others = word.Substring(index, word.Length - index);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the suggestions in comments this worked for what I am trying to do.

```
            int matches = 0;
            string lastID = words3[7].Substring(0, 8);
            for (int j = 7;  j < words2.Count(); j++)
            { 
                 string  results  = null;
                //"results" is the current employee information line  
                results = words3[j];

                //The ID number of that employee 
                 string id = results.Substring(0, 8);

                //Find and get all of the lines that start with employee ID from string[] words3
                if ( !words3[j].Contains(lastID))
                 { 

                    //j-matches are the indexes that match
                     for (int x = j - matches; x < j; x++)
                     {
                         Console.WriteLine(words3[j]);
                     }
                    //Found all of the matches so reset for new upcoming IDs
                     matches = 0;
                 }
                else
                {
                    matches++;
                }  

                if (lastID != id)
                 {
                     lastID = id;
                 }
            }
```